# Export multiple tierprices of single product

Tags: magento-1.8, import, export

I'm export/importing products including the tier price to a CSV file:

```
foreach($products as $productid) {
    $existingTierPrice = $product ->load($productid)->tier_price;

    foreach($existingTierPrice as $key=>$value) {
        $tierarray = array("all","all",$value['price_qty'],$value['price']);
        print stripslashes(implode('^',$tierarray)) . "\n";
    }
}
```

This works great but what to do when a product has multiple tier prices?

So in other words, how can i use the above code and make sure multiple tierprices of a product get exported and the tierprices can be edited and imported again into Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Please try bellow code

```
$productId = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$insetTierPrice[] = array(
    'website_id' => 1,
    'cust_group' => Mage_Customer_Model_Group::CUST_GROUP_ALL,
    'price_qty'  => 2,
    'price'      => 2
);
$insetTierPrice[] = array(
    'website_id' => 1,
    'cust_group' => Mage_Customer_Model_Group::CUST_GROUP_ALL,
    'price_qty'  => 3,
    'price'      => 3
);
$product->setData('tier_price', $insetTierPrice);
try {
    $product->save();
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but what i mean is how can i use my code and make sure multiple tierprices of 1 product get exported and the tierprices can ben edited and imported again into Magento